# How to properly escape a quoted command after a line continuation?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Running the following example batch file,

```
echo foo &&^
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

...produces the following output:

> ```
> foo
> '"C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> ```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

As tagged, this question is dealing with Windows (XP) batch files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, but nearly all answers are wrong, or don't understand what happens.

The problem is independent of cmd-line or if it is inside of a batch file.

The rule for the caret multiline character:
A caret at a line end, appends the next line **and escapes the first character of the appended line!**
That's the cause why you got

```
echo foo ^
&& echo bar
---- OUTPUT ---
foo &
bar
---------------

rem equivalent to
echo foo ^&& echo bar
rem So the first ampersand is escaped and the second works as a single &
```

That's also the cause why the original code can't work

```
echo foo &&^
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

rem is equivalent to this, so the quote will be escaped
echo foo &&^"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

And why the other solution works?

```
echo foo &&^
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

rem is equivalent to
echo foo &&^cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

And if you are escaping the "c" or not is not important for the "cmd".

**There is a way to get the second line working without modifing it.**

```
echo foo && >con ^
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

This is **a special case of a special case**, the caret works as a normal multiline, but without escaping the first character. (I suppose, cmd.exe is not programmed, it comes out of the chaos).

Comment: Thank you for this! I thought I was going crazy. Another simple remedy is add a space at the beginning of the quoted line following caret.

Answer (score 1):

Quotation marks do seem to be properly parsed by cmd.exe when they are preceded by conditional processing symbols (i.e., `&`, `&&`, `||`).

As a work-around you can use a path that contains short names only without white space characters:

```
echo foo &&^
C:\Progra~1\Intern~1\iexplore.exe
```

Or use a helper variable with delayed variable expansion:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "IE_EXE=C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"

echo foo &&^
!IE_EXE!
```

Comment: second solution sends a wrong commandline to iexplore. It will try to open `http://files/Internet%20Explorer/iexplore.exe`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work too:

```
echo foo &&^
cmd /c "C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting && on the second line.

```
echo foo ^
&& "C:\Program files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

Edit: As the Question asks, this command must be run in a batch file.  It works from the batch file but works incorrectly at the command line!

Comment: this will display `foo &` and will execute the second command also if the first command fails.

Comment: This command works correctly if you put it in the batch file as the OP indicated.  Please try the command in a batch file.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the ampersands.

```
echo foo ^ 
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

I get

```
C:\Users\keith\Desktop>echo foo
foo

C:\Users\keith\Desktop>"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

edit - I didn't have `@echo off` at the top of my batch file.

Comment: If you remove the ampersands you change the behavior of the commands.  The ampersands indicate that the second command should only run if the first command succeeds.

Comment: Yeah, I tried placing the ampersands on the second line as you suggested above and it ended up echoing 'foo &'

Comment: yes, that is true if you run it from a cmd line.  The question indicates it should be in a batch file.  It works differently in the batch file.

Comment: no, I mean, I created this batch file and ran it from my desktop and  received the echo indicated above.  Im running windows 7 currently... could be the difference.

Answer (score -1):

You need to quote the path if it contains spaces; I'm not quite sure what language you're dealing with, but basically you need:

```
""C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe""
```

Comment: Windows (XP) batch file. New error:
'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.